# How to make Sunspot works with Mongoid + Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I was writing a Blog like application Using Rails3/Mongoid, and now trying to use Sunspot for full-text search

I follow these steps: https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot , install this https://github.com/jugyo/sunspot_mongoid as plugin, and add the following code to make the `sunspot:reindex` work correctly,

```
module Mongoid
  module BaseModel
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      scope :recent, desc(:_id)
      scope :exclude_ids, Proc.new { |ids| where(:_id.nin => ids.map(&:to_i)) }
    end

    module ClassMethods
      # like ActiveRecord find_by_id
      #def find_by_id(id)
      #  if id.is_a?(Integer) or id.is_a?(String)
      #    where(:_id => id.to_i).first
      #  else
      #    nil
      #  end
      #end

      def find_in_batches(opts = {})
        batch_size = opts[:batch_size] || 1000
        start = opts.delete(:start).to_i || 0
        objects = self.limit(batch_size).skip(start)
        t = Time.new
        while objects.any?
          yield objects
          start += batch_size
          # Rails.logger.debug("processed #{start} records in #{Time.new - t} seconds") if Rails.logger.debug?
          break if objects.size < batch_size
          objects = self.limit(batch_size).skip(start)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and in my post model :

```
  include Sunspot::Mongoid
  searchable do
    text :title, :stored => true
    text :content, :stored => true
    text :comments, :stored => true do
      comments.map { |comment| comment.content }
    end                                                                                                  
    time :last_comment_at
  end
```

but when i use `@search = Post.search` it always give me this error ..

```
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind in SearchController#index
Calling Document#find with nil is invalid
```

I find it may be conflict to Mongoid or something，and change it to `Post.solr_search`

but it still can't work ：

```
[parano@u330 attix.us]$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start 
:public is no longer used to avoid overloading Module#public, use :public_folder instead
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server.rb:12:in `<class:Server>'
Removing stale PID file at /home/parano/code/rails_projects/attix.us/solr/pids/development/sunspot-solr-development.pid
Successfully started Solr ...


[parano@u330 attix.us]$ rails console
:public is no longer used to avoid overloading Module#public, use :public_folder instead
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server.rb:12:in `<class:Server>'
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.3)

ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > p = Post.solr_search { fulltext 'vero' }

 => <Sunspot::Search:{:fq=>["type:Post"], :q=>"vero", :fl=>"* score", :qf=>"title_texts content_texts comments_texts", :defType=>"dismax", :start=>0, :rows=>30}> 

ruby-1.9.3-p0 :002 > p.results

NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for #<Array:0xb4916b8>
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mongoid-2.3.4/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:382:in `method_missing'
    from /home/parano/code/rails_projects/attix.us/vendor/plugins/sunspot_mongoid/lib/sunspot/mongoid.rb:45:in `criteria'
    from /home/parano/code/rails_projects/attix.us/vendor/plugins/sunspot_mongoid/lib/sunspot/mongoid.rb:39:in `load_all'
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:228:in `block in populate_hits'
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:224:in `each_pair'
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:224:in `populate_hits'
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/search/hit.rb:90:in `result'
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:275:in `block in verified_hits'
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/search/paginated_collection.rb:50:in `select'
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/search/paginated_collection.rb:50:in `method_missing'
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:275:in `verified_hits'
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:59:in `results'
    from (irb):2
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/parano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'ruby-1.9.3-p0 :003 >
```

anyone can help me ?

Comment: I am having an issue with the re-indexing in solr. U have mentioned that adding the above code would solve that issue but to which file should I add that code for re-indexing to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very beta. I tried to make the simplest example work with sunspot_mongoid and had no luck. No rake tasks included, might be related to this issue on github:

https://github.com/jugyo/sunspot_mongoid/issues/7

Maybe if you file an issue over there the maintainer will be able to take a look and respond.

Comment: In the description on github it says sunspot_mongoid is "no longer maintained" :(  Last commit is from a year ago.

Comment: Yeah, elastic search seems like a much better choice these days.

Comment: Are you using the tire gem with elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

I've updated `sunspot_mongoid` and now it works nice :D https://github.com/hlegius/sunspot_mongoid2

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I use only sunspot_rails gem. Here is my Sunspot config file:

```
Sunspot.config.pagination.default_per_page = 24

module MongoidAdapter
  class InstanceAdapter < Sunspot::Adapters::InstanceAdapter
    def id
      @instance.id.to_s
    end
  end

  class DataAccessor < Sunspot::Adapters::DataAccessor
    def load(id)
      @clazz.criteria.for_ids(BSON::ObjectId(id))
    end

    def load_all(ids)
      @clazz.criteria.in(:_id => ids.map {|id| BSON::ObjectId(id)})
    end
  end
end

Sunspot::Adapters::DataAccessor.register(MongoidAdapter::DataAccessor, Mongoid::Document)
Sunspot::Adapters::InstanceAdapter.register(MongoidAdapter::InstanceAdapter, Mongoid::Document)
```

Comment: What version of Mongoid and Sunspot Rails are you using this with?

Comment: mongoid 2.4.10, sunspot_rails 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use sunspot with mongo you can use sunspot_mongo (works with mongo mapper & mongoid)
https://github.com/derekharmel/sunspot_mongo

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 active forks of the project.

You can see all 70 forks and choose which one you like best here:

https://github.com/jugyo/sunspot_mongoid/network

I'm currently using the new sunspot_mongoid2 gem mentioned by hlegius (thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

I might add that there is a new gem called [sunspot_mongoid2](https://github.com/hlegius/sunspot_mongoid2) that worked for me where sunspot_mongoid was failing terribly.

I haven't looked at the code itself, but from GitHub it seems sunspot_mongoid has not received any relevant updates for quite some time.